# vscode - visual studio code - dots / elipsis before brackets

Tags: visual-studio-code

In the latest updated of vscode they show the following image for bracket pair colorization:
[image]

From there I am interested in the dots that are display before / to the left of every bracket. What is the name of this function? how can I active it in vscode?

Comment: Is that bracket colorization a new feature? I'm currently using an extension for that - would be good to need one less extension 

Comment: Yes, it came recently and now is even in the section of code navigation:
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/editingevolved#_bracket-matching

Answer (score 1):

The answer for this is that this is called `render white space` and can be modified from the standard settings in vscode.

[image]

set to all to achieve the desired result.